# TypeScript localization issues

Tags: localization, typescript

If I use typescript and declare a string there, and set that string to some Russian text.
Then typescript compiler compiles to JavaScript with no regard to encoding I use in solution.
So I get that "questions in rombic symbols" instead of normal letters.

So, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you post code on what you've done so far?

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript as default creates an ANSI encoded file when added using visual studio. (or visual studio creates ansi files as standard)

To fix open the file in notepad and use "save as" and change the encoding to UTF8 or UNICODE.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your file encoding to UNICODE. 
Compiling:

```
var x = "привет мир";

class foo {
    public done() {
        return "привет мир";
    }
}
```

Gave the following JS for me:

```
var x = "привет мир";
var foo = (function () {
    function foo() { }
    foo.prototype.done = function () {
        return "привет мир";
    };
    return foo;
})();
```

Comment: where should I change encoding to UNICODE?

Comment: You know, what's strange. TypeScript edit window shows generated JS - in there I see broked encoding. And in browser UI too (if I alert something). But when I open generated JSfile in browser - every russian letter is ok! Strange! Perhaps browsers correct encoding on the fly.

Comment: Copy paste the code with Russian characters into notepad. Hit ctrl+s it will as you to create a UNICODE file. This works fine for me in the browser as well. Please check your browser settings if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when I use cscript to run tsc.js compiler.

I've found that the input file for tsc should be in utf-8 **with signature** (BOM) or unicode-16 encoding.

If I use nodejs to run tsc.js the input file could be in utf-8 even without signature and everything is ok.