# Transpiled JavaScript output contains invalid characters in literals

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have a field definition in TypeScript that looks like that:

```
languages: Array<{}> = [{ key: "fr", name: "français" }];
```

When the TypeScript file gets compiled the output in the JavaScript looks like:

```
this.languages = [{ key: "fr", name: "fran�ais" }];
```

Why does the transpiler change the literals and how can I prevent that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript localization issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808799/typescript-localization-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, got it by myself...

The TypeScript file was saved using the default `Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252` encoding; I changed that to `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001)` which fixed the problem.